# Swift protocols mutability

Tags: swift, struct, swift-protocols

I'm currently a bit confused about gettable properties in protocols. Consider this example:

```swift
protocol Person {
    var name: String { get }
}
```

I expected the `name` property to be read-only, but I found that you could change the value without compiler complaints:

```swift
struct Driver: Person {
    var name: String
}

var driver = Driver(name: "Ryan")
driver.name = "Changed!"
```

If we define `driver` with `let` keyword, then compiler raises the error, but if I understand correctly, it has nothing to do with protocols, as constant structs are immutable by design in Swift.

Method interactions behave as I would've expected:

```
extension Person {
    mutating func changeName(_ newName: String) {
        self.name = newName    // Error: 'name' is a get-only property
    }
}
```

I'm new to Swift, and the nuance mentioned may not have any practical use, but this behavior made me ask myself if I lack some basic understanding of how structs work.

Comment: `protocol` defines mimimal interface to be implemented. Your protocol `Person` asks from implementing types to have `String` property named `name` that can be **at least** readable. Ability to `set` is extra functionality, and protocol doesn't limit you from that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The protocol requirement is

> a variable `name` which can be read

which doesn't mean that the variable in a struct adopting this protocol is necessarily read-only.

In the code you are changing the variable directly in the `Driver` type, the protocol is not involved.

On the other hand if you annotate the protocol type you get the expected error

```
var driver : Person = Driver(name: "Ryan")
driver.name = "Changed!" // Cannot assign to property: 'name' is a get-only property
```

Answer (score 4):

A protocol only declares the required interface, but not the full interface of conforming types. Your conforming types can add extra properties/methods that aren't required by the protocol.

The same is true for getters and setter. If a protocol property requirement is `get`, that means the conformant type must have a getter for the property, but doesn't mean it cannot have a `setter` for it as well.

However, the same doesn't work the other way around. If a protocol declares a property as `{ get set }`, that property must have a setter (be mutable).

Answer (score 3):

The apple [documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Declarations.html) explains this very well.

> The getter and setter requirements can be satisfied by a conforming type in a variety of ways. If a property declaration includes both the get and set keywords, a conforming type can implement it with a stored variable property or a computed property that is both readable and writeable (that is, one that implements both a getter and a setter). However, that property declaration can’t be implemented as a constant property or a read-only computed property. If a property declaration includes only the get keyword, it can be implemented as any kind of property.